# How to call a method of a derived class in the constructor of this derived class

Tags: typescript, visual-studio

I have a piece of code that used to work in TypeScript a few years ago, but now is begin compiled using Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild 4.5.3 (as part of a Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web NET 5.0 project) and no longer works. Previously code must have been compiled using an older version of this compiler, but I can't pinpoint which version (it was a TypeScript project in Visual studio 2017 or older). Here is a stripped down version of my code:

```
class MyArray extends Array<number>{
    constructor(x: number)
    {
        super();
        this.foo(x);
    }

    foo(x: number) {
        // Do stuff with x
    }
}
```

Creating a new instance of MyArray results in the exception: **Uncaught TypeError: _this.foo is not a function**

It appears to boil down to the constructor being compiled to:

```
var _this = _super.call(this) || this;
_this.foo(x)
```

If I understand it correctly, `_this` is an instance of an `Array<number>` and knows nothing of my `foo` method.

In the past the constructor would compile to:

```
_super.call(this);
this.foo(x)
```

which would work.

I desperately tried to find an answer to this problem on the internet, but had no luck. Adding to the confusion, intelisense and the compiler don't expect there to be a problem (probably because this code would work in a non-inherited class) and the debugger in the browser still firmly believes that `this` in my TypeScript constructor is an instance of `MyArray` rather than `Array<number>`.

**Long story short, how can I call my `foo` method from the constructor of `MyArray` class?**

Comment: Can you share your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: It's failing for target `ES5`.

Comment: Try a target forward than `ES5`, like `ES2015` or `ESNEXT` etc...

Comment: I didn't have `tsconfig.json` before and I don't have it now, but your target remark gave me a clue. I went to my project settings and changed ECMAScript version to **2017** (was set to **ES5**) and my app is working again. Still I would like to know how/if I can call my `foo` method in ES5

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to tips form **Nalin Ranjan**, I was able to figure out how to solve my problem. After switching my project to Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web NET 5.0 I made no adjustments to the TypeScript compiler configuration. For some reason that meant my target was **ES5** (I mistakenly expected it to default to a newer version of TypeScript and ES5 to somehow be a newer target). After changing the target to **ES2017** (which I probably had in the old version of my project), everything started working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to have a `foo` being called the way we want to with `ES5` target, try this...

```typescript
class MyArray  extends Array<number> {
    constructor(x: number) {
        super();
        this.foo(x);
    }

    // A property foo as arrow function, instead of a member function on the class
    foo = (x: number) => {
        // Do stuff with x
        console.log('foo called with', x);
    }
}

let c = new MyArray(6);
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=1&noImplicitUseStrict=false&ts=4.5.4&useDefineForClassFields=true#code/LAKAxgNghgzjAEBZAngQQE7qs+8CmAHgC54B2AJghlsgDykCuAtgEZ7oB88A3qLrmAD2pGEXQMwRQegAUBAFzxGrdgEoefflpgMADuxmqA3Jq24iACwCWMAHQAzQYLnHT8AL6g3jwfAC88HKKymzo6n5cvCBm-AD0sfAAIr6iDPb28ADuVpbwBG5aQiKCEHi2EIIA5jIA5D7wYFAQpeRZORY1ADR5rtH8niADoKVEDf5KeJlIaJjYMgBsvWAOTjIAjAAMvaBAA)